# NPM LINK how my team get the code while the shared module not push to npm or even registered at the package json

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-link

So I just try to use `npm link` for my multi project, everything work just fine for now, but one thing that i dont understand is since the shared folder not registered in the package.json and the `node_modules` folder not pushed to the remote repo then how my other team can get the code that being shared in my local ? it will done if i can change the directory of where the symlink will be placed (anywhere but not node_modules folder)
Please help or give some explanation here
Thanks